# fbx material show correctly in unity but import to maya show wrong material

Tags: unity, maya

see my gif, fbx material work well in unity preview, but when import it in maya, face material show wrong

here is [my fbx](https://skfb.ly/6zGsM)

I use unitychan material in this [unity asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/characters/unity-chan-model-18705)

in unity
[image]

in maya

[image]

the strange thing is in maya I use eye image material but show pure color material

[image]

Comment: Does it look wrong in just the viewport or in the render view as well?

Comment: @ChantelleBadenhorst render view only can open image, of course, the image texture show correct